# Example of a sequence that converges uniformly on each compact subset of $\mathbb{D}$, but does not converge uniformly on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, examples-counterexamples, uniform-convergence

Here is an old exam problem that I still can't figure out: Let $M > 0$ and consider the set $\mathcal{F}$ of all functions $f$ such that $$ f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n}z^n $$ with $a_n \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n|\leq M $. Give an example of a sequence $\{f_k\}\subset \mathcal{F}$ that converges uniformly on each compact subset of $\mathbb{D}$, but does not converge uniformly on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$.

Any insights will be appreciated. It will be especially helpful if the thinking process of forming an example is explained. Thanks.

Comment: What sequence that converges uniformly on each compact subset of $\mathbb{D}$ have you tried?

Comment: $f_n(z)=\sum_{j=0}^n\frac{z^j}{j^2}$,$f_n(z)=\sum_{j=0}^n\frac{z^j}{j}$, $f_n(z)=z$,etc. Nothing's on point. I do not recall a sequence satisfies the hypothesis. I know $\mathcal{F}$ is a normal family. I don't have much clue at this point

Comment: @reuns: Do you mean something like $1/(1-z)$? But the coefficients are 1?

Comment: Where does its Taylor series converge uniformly ?

Comment: @reuns: The compact subsets of the unit disk.

Comment: Reading again your question, as $M$ should not depend on $f_n$, simply take $f_n(z)= z^n$

Comment: @reuns. You should take $f_n(z)=Mz^n$ so that the sum of the co-efficients of $f_n$  is $M,$ not $1.$

Comment: @reuns: Ah that works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: You're right. Thank you.

Comment: My suggested modification of the example in the  last comment above by "reuns"  will work, and I think the point is that we can take $ f_n$  to be a suitable  polynomial such that $f_n(z)$  converges to $0$ when $|z|<1$ but $f_n(z)$ does not even converge  for most $z$ for which $|z|=1.$  It is easy to forget that polynomials are power series and that polynomial solutions may often  be easier to find.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Thanks for your insights!